# Come from behind, sneak up on someone from behind,walk up to from behind

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

Our teacher was telling us about a "murder" in our psychology class.  So she said:

> A man **came from behind** and stabbed a lady.
>
> A man **sneaked up from behind** and stabbed a lady.
>
> A man **walked up to the lady from behind** and stabbed her.

Do the bold words sound natural in this context?

Comment: Yes, to me they sound correct

Comment: I have a slight issue with all of them. I would prefer to hear *from behind* ***her*** in some way, rather than conflating the pronoun with the second clause that follows. In some contexts you can *just* say *from behind* (when nothing else follows), but here it seems a little bit strange. At least to me. I'm sure it sounds normal to a lot of other people. So, it's not a problem. It's just that my *personal* choice would be to rephrase them slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the debate whether it sounds better to say *sneaked* or *snuck* (more a question of dialect rather than grammar), they're fine.

Some writers might think these overly wordy though, as "stabbed from behind" pretty much includes the concept that the murderer *approached* the victim from behind, and caught her unawares.

> The man **stabbed** her **from behind**, and vanished before anyone could get a good look at his face.

Naturally this depends on the situation.  In a police report, for example, it might be important to explicitly say the murderer made no attempt at stealth:

> According to witnesses, the suspect **walked up** to the woman from behind, without any indication he intended violence.  He then proceeded to stab her one time in the chest before running away.

Comment: And what about "came from behind"? Does it sound natural? And what about "he snuck up from behind and stabbed her"? Do both of them sound natural?

Comment: So what do you think @Andrew?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish   "Came from behind" is fine.